# How to remove the "Show -> Hidden items" option from Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

I don't want this option visible in the windows explorer. How do I remove it on Windows 11 Pro

I tried removing and changing some things in the registry, or looked for outdated entries that are no longer there

Comment: On a native Windows 11 system, show Hidden Items is buried in the 3 dots ...   Otherwise if is not seen.

Comment: It can’t be removed. You can use a different shell other than File Explorer.

Comment: @John definitely not buried. I open D, there is a prominent View menu, when I click it, the last option is Show - and it displays a submenu, one of the options being "Hidden items". What is the point of hiding items when they can just be revealed

Comment: @Ramhound what do you recommend? And can I disable Windows Explorer if Im happy with the replacement

Comment: On all of my Windows Explorer instances (3 machines) Show Hidden Items is always in the 3 dots. Something unusual about your installation

Comment: @KaloyanRoussev - I cannot and will not recommend a specific shell replacement for File Explorer. Why does something that has been around for 20 years need removing? Hidden system files was never about security. It was simply to hide files a user should never have to worry about. If your using hidden files as a security feature, my recommendation, is to use the ACL instead.

Comment: Please explain the use case here.  Is this for every user machine in a domain environment or just your non-domain joined machine?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-10/229050-remove-file-name-extensions-hidden-items-option-file-explorer.html).  It won't remove the option but it claims to disable the selection.